# .htaccess rule creates infinite loop

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I want to redirect my wordpress blog from http to https and added this code to my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Once i open the url i am getting a redirect loop error.

I have no development background, and therefore no clue how to modify the htaccess to fix this issue.

Would be great getting your advice!
Thanks a lot in advance...

the updated htaccess reads this:

```
# BEGIN All In One WP Security
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_WP_FILE_ACCESS_START
<Files license.txt>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
<Files wp-config-sample.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
<Files readme.html>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_WP_FILE_ACCESS_END
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
ServerSignature Off
LimitRequestBody 10240000
<Files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_IP_BLACKLIST_START
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from 178.175.131.0/24
#AIOWPS_IP_BLACKLIST_END
#AIOWPS_PREVENT_IMAGE_HOTLINKS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(.*)?\.mywebsitename\.de [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ - [F,NC,L]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_PREVENT_IMAGE_HOTLINKS_END
# END All In One WP Security

# redirect from http to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


# HTTP-Kompression einrichten
# mod_gzip_on yes

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>


# Caching einrichten
FileETag MTime Size
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 months"
## STOP REFERRER SPAM
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
# Set Referrer Spam as spambot
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer semalt.com spambot=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer buttons-for-website.com spambot=yes
## add all the SPAM sites you want
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=spambot
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress



<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Where is it installed your https certificate, on your web server or you're behind a load balancer with https installed?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to improve your question with sufficient information to describe and reproduce your problem.

Comment: the website runs on strato.de with a standard hosting package. Unfortunaltely i have no information/no influence where the ssl certificate is installed because it is part of the hosting package.